# Does the ADA prevent private entities from asking customers if they have a disability?

Tags: united-states, medical, disabilities

Some people have claimed that if a potential customer without a mask attempts to enter a privately owned store/business, then the [Americans with Disabilities Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americans_with_Disabilities_Act_of_1990) makes it illegal to ask the person if they have a disability which prevents them from wearing a mask.  Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

The ADA does not prohibit private entities from asking potential customers about disabilities.  Title I, Section 102 (c) [**Medical Examinations and Inquiries**] puts limits on what an *employer* can ask potential *employees*. Title III, sections 301 through 310, which covers public accommodations and services operated by private entities, does not mention medical inquiries at all.

For reference, [here is the text of ADA](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/STATUTE-104/pdf/STATUTE-104-Pg327.pdf).